# Title of novelette - planet with cannibalism

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-colonization

I've been looking for a title of novelette about a planet that is ruled by king/ruler who sends his man regularly among people so he can hypnotize them and harvest flesh by cutting it off for the king's meal. As a result, the people on this planet are crippled, with cut out organs.

In the ending twist it turns out that the planet was to be an Earth's colony, but their spaceship crashed and it was cut off from the rest of the world for a long time.

I'd say it was either by Philip K. Dick or Stephen King. Or at least in their climate.

Comment: When did you read it?

Comment: Probably I found it: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154664/short-story-about-shepherd-saving-his-people-from-human-eating-aliens - need to double check, but "Shepard" rights the bell. I read it like ~20 years ago, the anthology was older, thou.

Comment: @JacekMossakowski
If you think that's the right answer, let us know so we can close it as a duplicate. You have a fine question, but we like to consolidate to improve the ability of the system to help people in the future.

Comment: If you want, you can even post it as an answer (and accept it 48 hours after the asking), especially if you can provide details not in the linked question. Again, it helps us help others in the future. And it might net you some points. :) That said, if you do so, make it a good answer that provides the name of the work (a lot of people like to link to an online source of information) and details of how it matches.

Comment: Wait a minute, Statue of Liberty? That was our planet! You maniacs, you blew it up!